Is it possible to show a different data series in the data table below a chart (for example, to show a percent growth rate)?
I have this dataset displayed in a PowerPoint chart. I have also calculated the simple percentage growth rate between Series 1 and Series 2 within each category. 19.7% for Category 1, -11.6% for Category 2, etc. Is it possible to customize the data table that is shown below the chart so that it shows a third series, such as this growth rate, instead of the data points themselves? The goal is for this table to be automatically generated, using the "data table" feature of PowerPoint/Excel charts.

The "data table" I'm referring to is the data table element in a PowerPoint or Excel chart.

Mockup of Goal

In the chart options for data labels, there is the "value from cells" option which lets me specify a different series to use for the labels. Unfortunately, I can't find an option like that for the data table. The ideal solution would have a table that says "Growth Rate" and then whatever values I calculate in the area below the chart.
Raw Data
This is the raw underlying data:
             Series 1   Series 2    Growth Rate
Category 1   2,068      2,476      19.7%
Category 2   2,760      2,439      -11.6%
Category 3   2,481      2,239      -9.8%
Category 4   1,221      1,365      11.8%



Hi what do you mean with data table? The title? BTW let A1=2068 and B1=2476... you can write in C1 cell =(1.-B1/B2) and format the cell as %. Repeat (CTRL - C) (CTRL-V) for all the needed cell, select and do a chart from that data...

Do you have fields containing the data you wish to represent, even calculated fields?

@music2myear Yes, the spreadsheet that underlies the chart has a separate column that calculates the percent growth rate. I can easily include that in the columns included in the chart or not. I'll edit the question to show a screenshot and the data as a table.

@Hastur I mean the "data table" element of a PowerPoint or Excel chart. I added a screenshot to show where you click to add that chart element. I'm just trying to customize that chart element.

@MichaelA I'm still a little confused: what is the goal you intend to achieve? In your example would you like percentages written above instead of values? (And in this case how since you have two series and the percentage is the change between these two series?) Maybe in pencil on a sheet of paper, but could you give an example of what you want to achieve as result?

@Hastur I added a mockup. My goal is to use the built-in data table feature of Excel/PowerPoint charts to automatically add the growth rate (or whatever other calculation I want) below the chart. I know I can just add a table manually, but then, if the values in the chart change, I have to update the table manually. Does that make more sense?

Now I understand (+1). I can suggest an alternative solution: for the labels of the second series, for example, you may try to use a cell with the text formatted with the second value and the percentage difference: 2476 (+19.7%) or the opposite +19.7% (2476). This way it will automatically update if you change the values ​​or add more categories. Note that it should be possible to format the text value with newlines too... Good Luck.

A workaround
I don't know if it is possible to use that feature for your purpose, at least in the way you imagined.
I can suggest a workaround: for the labels of the second series, for example, you could try using a cell with the text formatted with the second value and the percentage difference: 2476 (+19.7%) or the opposite + 19.7% (2476) - depends on which info you want to put the emphasis on.
This way it will automatically update if you change the values ​​or add more categories. Note that it should be possible to format (CONCAT) the text value with newline characters too.

Thank you. I've used that solution before, with CONCAT combined with CHAR(10) to get a new line in there. I'm still hoping for a solution that uses the table, but I'll be the first one to admit that PowerPoint/Excel charts aren't the most flexible solution sometimes!
